# Blended Data in Data Studio - Matrix Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
Name    Manager Area
Alan    Mark    North
Brian   Mark    North
Craig   Mark    North
David   Neil    East
Edward  Neil    East
Fred    Neil    East
```

And another that looks like

```
Manager Area    SomeField
Mark    North   foo
Neil    East    bar
```

So far these two connect together really well using Manager as the key. I can use a Filter Control to select an Area or a Manager and I can see a table like this

```
Name    Manager     Area    SomeField
```

Which is perfect, now I want to add the distance the Name lives away from the area. I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
Name    Manager North   East
Alan    Mark    1   2
Brian   Mark    3   4
Craig   Mark    5   6
David   Neil    7   8
Edward  Neil    9   10
Fred    Neil    11  12
```

And I want a table in Data Studio to look like:

```
Name    Manager     Area    SomeField   MilesFrom
```

So if you use the Filter Control to select either North or East, it would populate that column respectively.

Is this possible in Data Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Not as such. You could achive it by reformatting your sheet to this format:

```
Name    Manager Area     Milesfrom
Alan    Mark    North    1  
Brian   Mark    North    3   
Craig   Mark    North    5   
David   Neil    North    7   
Edward  Neil    North    9  
Fred    Neil    North    11
Alan    Mark    East     2
Brian   Mark    East     4
Craig   Mark    East     6
David   Neil    East     8
Edward  Neil    East     10
Fred    Neil    East     12
```

Then filtering by Area

Comment: Interesting solution, unfortunately that isn't going to work for my project due to the amount of data involved - however I have come up with a very dodgy workaround: Have an iframe on google sites (effectively our intranet), and have JS randomly select from a list of URLs for the iframe src. Then design the sheet, have a script that clears the user selection at midnight, then duplicate the sheet X times. The JS then randomly picks a sheet - this will reduce collisions - which was a main driver for using Data Studio in this instance. Not perfect but fits my use case.

Comment: Sounds like a good work around. Data Studio is great for the price (!) but there's definitely a lot of workarounds still needed